# Are "identify this piece" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, topics

I have a few tunes in my head that I've heard somewhere / played long time ago. They are very famous pieces. I can type out the score, and I think around 4 bars would be sufficient for someone to identity the music.

Are these type of questions on topic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not on topic here as our [FAQ states](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange is for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. If you have a question about...
>
> - practice or performance technique
> - music theory, notation, history, or composition
> - technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof
> - instrument maintenance or repair
> - usage of specific music software or hardware
>
> and it is not about...
>
> - business or legal issues (some of the latter may be asked on Law.SE)
> - genre categorization or other concerns from the perspective of a listener rather than a musician (try Music Fans instead)
> - requesting external resources (questions should be specific and answerable on this site; external links are for references and supporting material)
> - **identifying a song, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc.**
> - transcription of specific works, including identifying notes/chords/meters/other elements in songs
> - shopping help — including product or music search — or buying/selling advice or recommendations
> - recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

They are instead on topic on [Music Fans SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/).